# Does temporary suspension remove moderator powers?

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, moderators, account-suspension

It is only curiosity. I know, moderators aren't suspended; first they are de-modded. After de-modding, they can probably be suspended, but I've never heard of it happening.

Maybe it is possible if the moderators are fighting, but I think it would cause a [CM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) intervention with at least one de-modding.

Thus, this question is a purely theoretical question. So:

- Can moderators suspend another moderator?
- If a moderator is suspended, (but not de-modded), can they use their moderator powers?
- If a moderator is suspended, can they use the normal, reputation-bound privileges of the ordinary users?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Can moderators suspend another moderator?

Yes.

> If a moderator is suspended, (but not de-modded), can they use their moderator powers?

Yes. Including unsuspending themselves.

> If a moderator is suspended, can they use the normal, reputation-bound privileges of the ordinary users?

Yes. They are still a moderator, after all.

Comment: Think I know the answer, but.... has it ever happened?

Comment: I would add that for whatever reason a mod might find themselves suspended, *un-suspending* themselves would almost certainly been seen as an abuse of that power.

Comment: @Robert well, it's all in theory anyway. I'm 100% sure that if a moderator will truly deserve suspension, he/she will lose the diamond first, and all of this won't be relevant anymore.

Comment: @Sha - yeah, it has happened, but only as a test, not for any behavior that would normally be grounds for suspension.

Comment: There may have been *one* exception to that "for science" thing. Both moderators involved are no longer moderators.